# Add Filter to magento 2 category product collection

Tags: magento2, filter, product-collection

a similar problem.
If i want filter product collection, create plugin for Layer (if use event the result will be the same).

[image]

[image]

The collection is correct and show only 2 products.
But the Pagination order Category Filter show 9 Products.

Why??

Comment: Hello, could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using an older version of **magento 2.X.**

This issue has been **resolved** at [#e012a48.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e012a481737ba124281581442f57231bee259aa4).

Need to modify library collection class:  `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php`

Comment: No i want to filter by a custom product attribut not by category.

Comment: im using Magento 2.1.3. Not working...

Answer (score 0):

Please use getSize() function on product collection before returning it. It will calculates all mandatory data for layered and toolbar.

```
$collection->getSize();
```

Before this line -

> return $collection;

Answer (score 0):

It's a Magento default bug, Issue is solved here.

Replace getSize() function code by below code.

```
public function getSize()
{
    $itemCount = count($this->_items);
    if ($this->_totalRecords === null || ($itemCount > 0 && $itemCount !== $this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = (int) $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return (int) $this->_totalRecords;
}
```

You can fix it by apply given changes to your core file.

Core file Path : vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php

**Note:** This is a temporary solution.